# Script in UNIX (Bash) to determine if the user is the owner of a file

Tags: unix, bash, script

Something that would take any number of arguments, where each argument would be a path to a file or directory. If the user does own a particular path then it should check it to see if the path represents a normal file AND if that file is executable. If it is, then your script should execute/run the file.

Thanks for any help I've been trying different things for too long and I'm frustrated.

Comment: Homework question? Regardless, you should really show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 4):

```
magic() {
    for p in "$@"; do
        [ -O "$p" -a -x "$p" ] && /bin/sh "$p"
    done
}
```

read 'man test' to see what the checks do.

Comment: Illegible showing off.

Comment: @tkadlubo: indeed. part to blame is display of <code> enclosed stuff here on superuser.

Answer (score 4):

The `-O` test checks if the current user is the owner of a file or folder.

```
if [ -O "$FILENAME" ]; then echo 'Owned!'; else echo 'Nope!'; fi
```

See [list of file test operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) (and [how to do tests in general](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tests.html).)

Using `stat` on *nix for this purpose is tricky to do portably due to differences between platforms.

Answer (score 3):

To get current user id you do:

```
id -u
```

to get owner of file, you do:

```
stat -c "%u" file.name
```

to test if one value is the same as the other you do:

```
if [ "$first" -eq "$second" ]
then
    ....
fi
```

Comment: ...and for looping on arguments consider `shift`...

Comment: Note that on OSX (and perhaps other BSD-alikes) you need to use ```stat -f "%u" file.name``` instead...